# AVAudioPlayer does not play audio file - swift

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer

I know it seems quite straightforward, but in a weird way AVAudioPlayer does not play audio file. I have this code. It is not go through catch and still sound does not play. I've checked on physical device, simulator and also checked sound volume. But still I can't hear sound.

```
//in ViewController as a property
let soundEffect: AVAudioPlayer!

//in viewDidLoad
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "success.mp3", ofType:nil)!
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    do {
        soundEffect = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        soundEffect.prepareToPlay()
        soundEffect.play()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.description)
    }
```

I also tried `let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "success", ofType:"mp3")!` but it didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 2):

Try making your AVAudioPlayer an instance variable. otherwise soundEffect is deallocated at the end of the do loop.

Comment: still there's no sound

Comment: Show how you have changed the code to accomplish this.

Comment: Are you sure that is the code you are using because it doesn't compile for me.  The reason is that the `soundEffect` variable is a let and must therefore be initialised in the view controller init and not in viewDidLoad.  To do that it should be a var.  If I do that my test mp3 plays fine.

Comment: iVar worked fine here. THX!